# Check for multiple variables containing null

Tags: javascript, loops, variables, null

I'm trying to set null values to `-`. I don't want to hardcode.
My code:

```
if (variable1 == null) {
    variable1 = "-";
}
```

Now I have 10 other variables I want to do the exact same thing with.

I'm sure I forgot something veery easy with loops...

Comment: This is indeed a good job for a loop, but you should probably group your variables into an array first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to make an array of variables names an loop through them and change the value of each one to `-` using `window['variable_name'] = 'value'`.

Hope this helps.

```js
var var_1=null;
var var_2='some text';
var var_3=null;
var var_4='not null';
var var_5=null;
var var_6=100;

var variables_names = ['var_1','var_2','var_3','var_4','var_5','var_6'];

for(var i=0; i < variables_names.length ; i++)
{
    var variable_name = variables_names[i];

    if ( window[variable_name] == null )
         window[variable_name] = '-';
}

console.log(var_1, var_2, var_3, var_4, var_5, var_6); // return - some text - not null - 100
```

Comment: Tried it like that too but I only want to replace it if the value's null..
(Tried with a simple if condition, didn't work though.)

Comment: Seems like there's something else not working with my code... It works in the console, not on my page though. Maybe because I have nested loops?

Comment: I'm not sure brother because i don't know what you have in full code, but try to use `console.log` to debug your code, read slowly and check console to make sure that there's no error.

Comment: Posting anything would be too much, thank you very much though. I'll try tomorrow. :)